# Ubuntu Software Center categories

Tags: 16.04, 18.04

[image: software center]

I installed Ubuntu 64 bit 16.04 version. 
I'm not able to view the different categories and many apps are unavailable.
First time I opened s/w center I could view the categories, editors pick, recommended etc, but now it's not visible... Pls help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this link](https://www.fosslinux.com/1768/fix-ubuntu-software-center-not-loading-issue-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts.htm) and others there seems to be issues with Software Center in 16.04. There are two suggested fixes:

**1. Upgrade System and Reinstall Gnome Software**

from the command line try the following:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt autoremove gnome-software && sudo apt install gnome-software
```

If this doesn't fix Software Center, perhaps you could use Synaptic instead.

**2. Use Synaptic Instead**

Synapic package manager pretty much always works when other GUI managers fail.

```
sudo apt install synaptic
```

---

**Edit**: the problem has been reported [in 18.04 as well](https://askubuntu.com/q/1146450/248158) and the solution is similar:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-software
```