# Ubuntu Software Center is buggy

Tags: software-center, bug-reporting

I can search software without any problem. But the only category there is "Add-ons". I already tried restarting my computer and ran `sudo apt-get update & upgrade` but it still only shows 1 category. Like so:

[image]

Comment: The correct command is `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` or even `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`.

Comment: I tried both of them. My Software Center is still broken.

Comment: Try `sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-software`.

Comment: No problem, glad you solved it.

Comment: @Jim maybe this could be marked as a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065634/ubuntu-software-center-categories ? I will edit the answer there to mention your fix.

Comment: @DKBose Go ahead, I'll be more than happy to help more people.